# jQuery Plugin nanoScroller refresh content

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, scrollbar

I am using [`nanoscroller`](https://github.com/jamesflorentino/nanoScrollerJS) to show a list of items.
However, in some cases, I load the content via ajax and modify the div.content of the nano.
The problem is that the content is not renedered, although it is there.

```
<div class="nano">
<div class="content>
<li> asddas </li> <!-- this is loaded via ajax -->
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you give example an jsbin or pluncker ?

Comment: I have the same problem for IE10 only

Answer (score 0):

Try to fire this on ajax success.

```
$(".nano").nanoScroller();
```

This will refresh the scrollbar.

Here are some good references that can help you with this.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

https://github.com/jamesflorentino/nanoScrollerJS

Comment: This is definitely the suggested update strategy as given in nanoScroller documentation on GitHub. However when dealing with Ajax requests re-initializing the nano scrollbar this way does not seem to solve the problem

Comment: Try using a callback and .load